# Convert mysql select results to json (array of arrays)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I need to encode a table content to JSON in order to insert it into a file.

The output has to be as following :

```
{
"name1":[{"id":"11","name":"name1","k1":"foo","k2":"bar"}],
"name2":[{"id":"12","name":"name2","k1":"foo","k2":"bar"}],
}
```

Indeed, each JSON "line" corresponds to the content of the mysql row and the name of each JSON array is the name of the 'name' column.

The only thing I could manage for the moment is this :

```
      $return_arr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bo_appart"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$index = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$return_arr[$index] = $row;
 $index++;
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

And here is the output I get :

```
[
{"id":"11","name":"name1","k1":"foo","k2":"bar"},
{"id":"12","name":"name2","k1":"foo","k2":"bar"},
]
```

Thanks a lot !!!

**UPDATED**

Working code :

```
$return_arr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bo_appart"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$return_arr[ $row['nom_appart'] ][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

}

Comment: That's brilliant. Do you have a question?

Comment: SO what is your actual problem? Just build the data structure you want, and `json_encode()` it.

Comment: I just edited so that you can see what I actually did. 

The problem is I do not manage to build the right structure :/

Comment: `$return_arr[ $row['name'] ][] = $row;` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is enough, to create the desired JSON:

```
$return_arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $return_arr[$row['name']][] = $row; #or $return_arr[$row['name']] = [$row];
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: I know array() works on all versions of PHP, but I really do like the [] notation that newer versions support. Old habits die hard :)

Comment: I dont know why Im still stuck with `array()` you are right `[]` is just cleaner, and `array()` looks like a function, one of PHP weirdness lol

Comment: why do you have extra brackets in `$return_arr[$row['name']][] = array($row);`? why not `$return_arr[$row['name']] = array($row);`?

Comment: @RobP it was to force the array brackets, I did not test to be honest, but `$return_arr[$row['name']][] = $row;` thanks for pointing out

Comment: It was redundant, I tested on eval.io. You can either add [] on the left side or force an array on the right side, but not both. I see you edited to fix! I personally find it more readable to make the right side an array, but whatever.

Comment: Yes Indeed you are right, I included your suggested version as well

Answer (score 2):

You were close. I noticed you want final output to be an object not an array, because the outer brackets are {} not []. So you need a different object type, and you need to use each row's name as the key for storing that row.

```
$return_obj = new stdClass();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bo_appart"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $return_obj->$name = [$row]; // for PHP < 5.4 use array($row)
}

echo json_encode($return_obj);
```

Comment: Btw, `json_encode()` will automatically convert associative arrays to objects. And in your new version, the last row will overwrite all others (if there are multiple for same name), but idk if the OP knows/cares about that

Comment: ah yes, and one can use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT on non_associative arrays as well (PHP > 5.3). I guess I just don't trust it enough ;) , but that is documented behavior.

Comment: @RobP Almost !!! 
Here is what I get : 
{"name1":{"id":"11","name":"name1","k1":"foo","k2":"bar"},
"name2":{"id":"12","name":"name2","k1":"foo","k2":"bar"},}

They need to be in array, we are closed to it

Comment: @RentYourParis I edited my answer to add brackets around $row, last line of the while loop

Comment: @RobP how are you appending the elements to `return_arr` I didnt see that

Comment: @meda I'm using an object, not an associative array. Last line of the while loop, add a property to the object with the name as the key, an an array containing the row as the corresponding value. I think it's valuable to learn syntax for handling objects in PHP, so a good exercise.

Comment: RobP yes I see now, @kingkero fixed the name in `json_encode`. +1 for this approach.

Comment: @meda yes it was a cut & paste mistake and kingkero was kind enough to correct it. Your answer is economical and correct also.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on it a lot of time and Create mash/mysql-json-serializer package.

https://github.com/AndreyMashukov/mysql-json-serializer

You can select Json_array of json_objects and etc. It support ManyToMany, oneToMany, manyToOne relations

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id',est_res.est_id,'name',est_res.est_name,'advert_groups',(SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id',adg.adg_id,'name',adg.adg_name)) FROM advert_group adg INNER JOIN estate est_2 ON est_2.est_id = adg.adg_estate WHERE est_2.est_id = est_res.est_id))) FROM (SELECT * FROM estate est LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) est_res
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bo_appart"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$return_arr[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Comment: OP = original poster (on StackOverflow: the person asking the question)

Comment: I said _basically_, meaning they do the same thing. OP uses `$index` = 0, 1, ... and you leave it out - resulting in exactly the same array